# merging list of multiple data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge all the data frames in my current environment into one data frame, initially I tried

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="Date"),list(ls()))
```

But this didn't work, just returning the a list of data frame names.

I know it will work if I do

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="Date"),list(df1,df2,df3....))
```

But why doesn't the initial attempt work?

Both

```
typeof(list(ls())) 
typeof(list(df1,df2,df3))
```

Return type "list"

What can I do if there are so many data frames I can't input them all into the Reduce function?

Comment: You could try `mget(ls())` instead

Comment: @docendodiscimus This just added an extra level of indexation to the list of names.

Comment: That's strange. Can you show how exactly you tried it?

Comment: @docendodiscimus That is exactly how I wrote it, the first example just returned a list of all the data frame names.

Comment: you cant store your data.frame in a list instead of having several variable in the global envrionment?

Comment: @NicE this produced a debug on merge.data.frame .

Comment: sorry edited my comment, ls just gives you the names, try using `lapply(as.list(ls()),get)` instead of `list(ls())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = lapply(Filter(function(x) class(get(x))=='data.frame', ls(env=globalenv())), get)
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="Date"),lst)
```